# How to set default archive image without overriding first attached image?

Tags: functions, filters, archives

I have hit a wall. I have archive pages with some posts that have featured images which display fine.
Some posts don't have featured images but the first attached image displays.
Some posts have no images and there is a blank space. I have been trying all day to find a way to display a fallback image for the posts with no images. The closest I have come is a filter that displays a default image if no featured image is set. That would be great but it overrides the posts that normally display the first attached image. My last attempt was to only display the default image if there was no featured image or attached image. It still overrides attached images. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. This is the last filter I have tried.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_image', 'default_featured_image_when_not_set', 10, 3          );
function default_featured_image_when_not_set( $post ) {
if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() || ( '' != $args['fallback']) ) {
return $post;
}
else
{
echo '<img src="' . get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/images/default-image.jpg" />';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use get_attached_media() function to check if the post has any attached images to it. Also, you use wrong logic operator. Your code would look like this:

```
$attached_images = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
if ( (get_the_post_thumbnail() == NULL) && empty($attached_images) ) {
 // show your default image
}
else
{
 // do nothing, I guess?
}
```